# pdepend, no releases available

Tags: php, jenkins, centos, pear, pdepend

I'm trying to install [PDepend](http://pdepend.org/) on my Centos 6.3 server. For some reason I constantly receive an error that there are no packages/releases available.

Things I already executed:

- pear upgrade
- pear clear-cache
- pear channel-discover pear.pdepend.org
- pear install pdepend
- pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend-beta
- pear remote-list -c pdepend

None of them pointing me in any direction. No errors occure except that there are no release available for package "pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend"

Strangest part is that I'm succesfull with installing pdepend on my Ubuntu server. In that case, the first 3 steps are the only ones needed to install pdepend.

Anybody a suggestion how I can install pdepend?

Comment: try this "pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend"

Comment: Still returning the message  "No releases available for package "pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend"
install failed". Also tried to clear the pear cache without any luck.

Comment: I've checked on a Win7 box, a Centos 6.0 box and a Centos 6.3 box all 64 bits, they all worked, check if the ip of pear.pdepend.org points to 83.169.19.161.

Comment: It points indeed to that IP. However, if I ping to that IP there is a package loss of 100%. A traceroute reaches till hop xe-0-0-0.dr-master.r2.cgn3.hosteurope.de (176.28.4.42), which is outside of my network. At least this give me a direction to investigate any further. Tnx

Comment: Hmm, routing doesn't seem to be the problem. Can it be because I'm running a 32 bit version?

Comment: I don't think so, is re-installing the OS an option ?